# Additional permissions to Facebook authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, facebook-authentication

I'm adding Facebook authentication to my new ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application. I'm following this article:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html

I added the following code snippet to my Startup Configure method that gets me the basic information about the user.

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.AppId = "myFacebookAppId";
   options.AppSecret = "myFacebookSecret";
});
```

I would like to request just one more things from Facebook which is the user's date of birth.

Where do I add this in my code?

Answer (score 1):

To request the user's date of birth, you need to:

- Update the `Scope` property to make sure the `user_birthday` scope is included by the Facebook middleware when creating the authorization request. If you **don't add the `user_birthday` scope**, Graph API will **never return the user's date of birth**: `options.Scope.Add("user_birthday");`
- Update the `Fields` property to include the `birthday` field, as suggested by @blowdart: `options.Fields.Add("birthday");`.

But note that the `Fields` property doesn't exist in ASP.NET 5 RC1 (the latest release ATM). Alternatively, [you can also replace the `UserInformationEndpoint` property to include the fields you need](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/620#issuecomment-165464501):

```
options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday,email,name";
```

Comment: @Sam did you have a chance to give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

The options class has a Fields property;

```
/// <summary>
/// The list of fields to retrieve from the UserInformationEndpoint.
/// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user
/// </summary>
public IList<string> Fields { get; }
```

Add `birthday` to the Fields property.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that simply adding the `birthday` field to the `Fields` property (that doesn't exist in RC1, BTW), is not enough: you also need to request the `user_birthday` scope.